# JavaFX - Mouse Event not triggering

Tags: java, events, button, user-interface, javafx

Here is my code :

```
Button start = new Button("Start");
    start.setPrefHeight(100d);
    start.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);        

    start.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            //ss.startServer();
            System.out.println("adfasddasfrwgafsdasdf");
        }

    });
```

The message does not get printed on the console at eclipse! I want the event to trigger when the mouse is released. What am I doing wrong?

Upon furthet investagation I realised that if I have another mouseReleased event on another node , it will fire more events!... why is that?
For example , here is the code I am using, when I press the start button , it prints Start and Reload!

```
 start.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            ss.startServer();
            System.out.println("Start");
            arg0.consume();
        }


    });
 Button stop = new Button("Stop");
    stop.setPrefHeight(100d);
    stop.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    stop.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            sc.stopServer();
            System.out.println("Stop");
            event.consume();
        }

    });
    Button reload = new Button("Reload");
    reload.setPrefHeight(100d);
    reload.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    start.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent some) {
            sc.reloadServer();
            System.out.println("Reload");
            some.consume();
        }

    });
```

Stop button works properly!
Anyway , if the other piece of code works , here it is(http://pastebin.com/4f55R2gN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typo'd your code.  You set your MouseReleased handler on the **start** object instead of **reload**.

```
    Button reload = new Button("Reload");
    reload.setPrefHeight(100d);
    reload.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    start.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
button.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
      System.out.println("button click and mouse released");
   }
});
```

The below works for me fine.

```
public class FxmlSample extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        Button button = new Button("Click me");
        button.setMinSize(50.0, 50.0);
        button.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("11111111111111");

            }
        });

        Button button_2 = new Button("Click me 2");
        button_2.setMinSize(50.0, 50.0);
        button_2.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("2222222222222");

            }
        });
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(button, button_2);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(vBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);      
        jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        frame.add(jfxPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my full code here : http://pastebin.com/4f55R2gN I dont get it. it should work fine